# header/footer and page content not setup properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am building a website and I am facing a position issue and I can't figure out why the footer is not properly placed.

So I have setup the App.js to display the header on top of the page and have always the footer at the bottom. But for some reasons when I am loading an other page such as here, the header is still ok but the footer and the page content overlap as in the image below. Do not pay attention to the header, it's cut because of the screenshort.

[image]

See how the content (txt, h tage and blue buttom) and the header overlap. I am looking to always have the content between the header and footer whatever happened.

it should like this:

[image]

Even the title is not shown on the picture

below are the App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';


import Home from './pages/Home';
import NoPages from './pages/NoPages';
import Discover from './pages/Discover';
import HowItWorks from './pages/HowItWork';
import CreateClassAndHost from './pages/CreateClassAndHost';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
import Messages from './pages/Messages';
import Settings from './pages/Settings';
import Logout from './pages/Logout';
import CreateClass from './pages/CreateClass';
import CreateHost from './pages/CreateHost';
import HereIsTheMission from './pages/HereIsTheMission';
import SuccessfullSubmission from './pages/SuccessfullSubmission';

import './App.css';

function App()  {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
        <div>
          <Header />
        </div>
        <div className='page-container'>
          <div className='content-wrap'>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={ Home } />
              <Route path="/discover" component={ Discover } />
              <Route path="/howitworks" component={ HowItWorks } />
              <Route path="/create" component={ CreateClassAndHost } />
              <Route path="/profile" component={ Profile } />
              <Route path="/messages" component={ Messages } />
              <Route path="/settings" component={ Settings } />
              <Route path="/logout" component={ Logout } />
              <Route path="/hereisthemission" component={ HereIsTheMission } />
              <Route path="/createaclass" component={ CreateClass } />
              <Route path="/createahost" component={ CreateHost } />
              <Route path="/successfull" component={ SuccessfullSubmission } />
              <Route path="*" component={ NoPages } />
            </Switch> 
          </div>
          <div className='footer'>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

and the associated css App.css

```
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 90vh;
}

.content-wrap {
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;
}
```

and the content is done in a separate file and loaded through the `/create` navlink

but it's look like the opport

Below are my content file:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import BlueButton from '../components/materialdesign/BlueButton';
import './CreateClassAndHost.js';

class CreateClassAndHost extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const CreateAClass = 
            <div className="tile">
                <h2 className="subtitle" >{TextContents.BeATeacher}</h2>
                <p className="text" >{TextContents.BeATeacherDesc}</p>
                <div className="button">
                <BlueButton textSize="13" link_href="/createaclass" text={TextContents.BeATeacherBtn} />
                </div>
            </div>;

        const CreateAHost = 
            <div className="tile">
                <h2 className="subtitle">{TextContents.HostAClass}</h2>
                <p className="text">{TextContents.HostAClassDesc}</p>
                <div className="button">
                <BlueButton textSize="13" link_href="/createahost" text={TextContents.HostAClassBtn} />
                </div>
            </div>;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1 className="title">{TextContents.CreateClassOrHostTitle}</h1>
                <div classname="section">
                    {CreateAClass}
                    {CreateAHost}
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }

}

export default CreateClassAndHost;
```

and the associatedc css:

```
.container {
    width: 650px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    top:30%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}


.section {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tile {
    position: relative;
    left: 12px;
    top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.title {
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #333333;
}

.subtitle {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 0.7;
    color: #333333;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;

}

.text {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #616161;
    width: 280px;
    height: 85px; 
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-container{
  height:100vh;
}

.header{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
}

.footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
text-align:center;
}

.footer-menu{
padding:10px;
background-color:yellow;
width:100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="header">
    <span>Heading1</span>
    <span>Heading2</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-menu">
        <span>Footer</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using flex-box. keep your html structure like below, and use below css

> note : `main` should have height equal to screen height

```css
body,html{
  height :100%;
}

.main{
  display :flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height:100%;
}

.page-container{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div className="main">
        <div className="header">
          <Header />
        </div>
        <div className='page-container'>
          <div className='content-wrap'>
          <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={ Home } />
          <Route path="/discover" component={ Discover } />
          <Route path="/howitworks" component={ HowItWorks } />
          <Route path="/create" component={ CreateClassAndHost } />
          <Route path="/profile" component={ Profile } />
          <Route path="/messages" component={ Messages } />
          <Route path="/settings" component={ Settings } />
          <Route path="/logout" component={ Logout } />
          <Route path="/hereisthemission" component={ HereIsTheMission } />
          <Route path="/createaclass" component={ CreateClass } />
          <Route path="/createahost" component={ CreateHost } />
          <Route path="/successfull" component={ SuccessfullSubmission } />
          <Route path="*" component={ NoPages } />
          </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='footer'>
            <Footer/>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```